# Obtain User Defaults in Different ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, uikit, userdefaults

I have my user defaults defined as follow in ViewControllerSettings 
`public let kAlertsKey = "ALERTS_KEY"` 
And it is modified through a switch and an `ìf` statement with the following code

```
if switchAlerts.isOn{
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: kAlertsKey)
            UserDefaults.standard.set("On", forKey: kAlertsKey)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            print("on")
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: kAlertsKey)
            UserDefaults.standard.set("Off", forKey: kAlertsKey)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            print("off")
        }
```

My desire is to share the status `On`or `Off` to 6 different ViewControllers:

- ViewControllerGUI
- ViewControllerCreate
- ViewControllerList
- ...

My idea was to create an Enum such as:

```
enum ToggleSwitch: Int{
    case On, Off
    
    var isActive: Bool{
        switch self {
        case .On:
            return true
        case .Off:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure on how to follow or what I need to return in my enum case and where do I call it in each ViewController.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all your enum does is return `true` for `.On` and `false` for `.Off`, you really don't need it -- you can just use a `Bool`. In terms of passing it to a ViewController, you can set a property on the view controller -- without more information about your code, it'll be hard to give more specific advice than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a simple extension to `UserDefaults`:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var isAlertsEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            return bool(forKey: "ALERT_KEY")
        }
        set {
            set(newValue, forKey: "ALERT_KEY")
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of an actual `Bool` value instead of working with special string values. Also note that there is no need to remove the old value before setting a new value.

You can use the property anywhere in your project.

For example:

```
let enabled = UserDefaults.standard.isAlertsEnabled
```

or:

```
UserDefaults.standard.isAlertsEnabled = switchAlerts.isOn
```

---

FYI - `synchronize()` is clearly marked as obsolete and shouldn't be used.